# Проблема при расширении массива

Tags: массивы, delphi, список

В чем может заключаться ошибка

> Incomparible types

при `SetLength(stud,length(stud)+1)` ?

```
program Project2;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils, windows;

type
  fullname = record
    surname:string;
    name:   string;
    midname:string;
  end;

  fulldate = record
    day:  integer;
    month:integer;
    year: integer;
  end;

  person = record
    fio:   fullname;
    adress:string;
    born:  fulldate;
    brain: double;
  end;

var
  student: array of person;

procedure newStud(var stud:array of person);
begin
  SetLength(stud,length(stud)+1);
...
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
  TArr = array of person;
var
  student : TArr;
  x,max_len:integer;
Procedure newStud(var stud:TArr);
begin
  SetLength(stud,length(stud)+1);
...
end;
```

Comment: Увы, не помогло

Comment: как не помогло, что пишет?

Comment: А нет, все в порядке, спасибо! Просто перед "TArr = array of person;" нужно type написать. А можно узнать, почему так? Или где об этом прочитать?

Comment: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html - посмотри здесь, почему нельзя применять SetLength к open array.

Comment: Я уже уяснил это. Просто впервые со списками столкнулся и думал, что массив в данном случае не будет рассматриваться, как открытый. И был неправ.

Answer (score 1):

У меня в похожем случае прошло что-то типа следующего:

```
  TArr = array of person;
  pArr = ^TArr;

var
  student : TArr;
  x,max_len:integer;
Procedure newStud(stud:pArr);
begin
  SetLength(stud^,length(stud^)+1);
...
end;
```

И соответственно вызов процедуры как

```
newStud(@student);
```

правда под TArr у меня выступал TArr = array of double;